# How do I set secrets in Jenkins Step

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-secrets

I am looking for a solution to inject secrets only during a Jenkins step:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.username=mySecretValue
spring.datasource.password=mySecretValue
...
```

Current State:

```
stage('Test') {
      agent {
          docker {
               image 'myregistry.com/maven:3-alpine'
                    reuseNode true
                }
       }
       steps {
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'maven-settings-my-services', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS verify'
                }
            }
...
```

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1)** Add a password job parameter for that secret. But the job have to be run manually, because need someone to input the secret.

```
// write the secret to application.property at any stage that
// prior to test and deployment stage

sh "echo spring.datasource.password=${params.DB_PASSWORD} >> application.property"
```

Option 2) Add the secret as Jenkins String Text credential. But adding credential needs Jenkins administrator access and also need considering update in future.

```
stage('test or deployment') {
   environment {
      DB_PASSWORD = credentials('<credential_id_of_the_secret>')
   }
   steps {
      sh "echo spring.datasource.password=${env.DB_PASSWORD} >> application.property" 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much -Yong for your support! I have implemented option 2, but I get for each param  null prompted in the log, like "echo spring.datasource.password=null". Credential Binding Plugin is installed. Do you may know why?

Comment: Correct it, should use `env.DB_PASSWORD `

Answer (score 1):

One way I did it, was to attach the secrets with the credentials-Plugin variable by variable:

```
 echo 'Attach properties for tests to property file:'
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'DB_PW', variable: 'SECRET_ENV')]) {
                sh 'echo spring.mydatabase.password=${SECRET_ENV} >> ./src/main/resources/application.properties'
```

Instead of "echo", "sed" would also an option to replace the empty value for the key instead of add the property to the end of the file.

The second way I did is to attach a complete property file, instead of a key/value pair. The property file contains all needed properties for the tests:

```
    echo 'Attach properties file for test runs:'   withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'TEST_PROPERTIES', variable: 'APPLICATION_PROPERTIES')]) {    dir('$WORKSPACE') {
  sh 'sed s#'/src/main/resources/' application.properties > TEST_PROPERTIES'
```

In both cases the secrets has to be deleted atter the run, otherwise they can be viewed in plaintext under the Workspace folder.